# Can't make Permalinks in Wordpress for SEO-Friendly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks

I have a problem when creating link for "SEO-Friendly" when using the WooCommerce plugin on Wordpress.

In Setting -> General -> Permalinks.

in this setting:

Common Setting: Post Name.
Optional: don't have anything change.
Product permalinks: Default.

When I added the new product, I click on this link to the product. URL show like that:

http://localhost/ducloc/product/banh-trang-nuong-nam-bo/

Example my product has the name: `banh-trang-nuong-nam-bo`.

But it shows error like:

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the
>   referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author
>   of that page about the error.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Image for setting in Permalinks:
[image]

Image for error when go to URL of Product:

[image]

Update: My `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ducloc/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /ducloc/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: try to check if mod_rewrite is turned on, and do post your htaccess,

Comment: @Exprator I updated my `.htaccess`

Comment: your htaccess seems to be fine, what os are you using? and what server are you using ?

Comment: I using Manjaro - a distro base on Arch Linux. Apache is defaulting my server. I was `sudo chmod -R 777 /ducloc`. `/ducloc` is WordPress source.

Comment: My friend using Windows. He doesn't have the problem like me.

Comment: check for turning on mod_rewrite for your os, then after turning it restart your apache and check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149188/discussion-between-vanloc-and-exprator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache configuration file

```
ubuntu -> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
arch -> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Add mod_rewrite and .htaccess support for your site At the end of the configuration files add these lines:

```
#My site mod_rewrite configuration
<Directory "/ABSOLUTE/PATH/YourSite">
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
Enable mod_rewrite

ubuntu: sudo a2enmod rewrite
arch: Uncomment, in apache configuration file, the line LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
Restart apache

ubuntu: sudo service apache2 restart
arch: sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

use this following settings for your arch linux